# Single word between learning and mastering?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there single word that describes that I learned and became proficient in using a skill but is not as strong as mastered.

I want to say, "I (blank)ed a new technique." I learned it, but I have also become quite proficient in using it. Although I am proficient, I wouldn't say I have mastered the technique.

Comment: What distinction are you making between ***proficiency*** and ***mastery*** here? I don't recognise any real distinction apart from the fact that your ***quite** proficient* implies *somewhat, but not **completely** proficient*.

Comment: Sounds like you aced the new technique.

Comment: One of the answers on the older question has **competent** (*I have become competent in XYZ*)  I think that fits, otherwise *Intermediate level/competency* if you want to state your level of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

> I *refined* a new technique

Could work.

#### [Refine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refine)

> Make minor changes so as to improve or clarify (a theory or method)
>
> *‘ease of access to computers has refined analysis and presentation of data’*

Answer (score 2):

"I acquired a new technique."

From ODO:
Learn or develop (a skill, habit, or quality).

Now that you are done learning, you would use this technique for doing stuff and hopefully become a master at it.

Answer (score 1):

**journeyman**

> A worker or sports player who is reliable but not outstanding.
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/journeyman)

*"I learned a new technique and now consider myself a journeyman practitioner."*

Comment: I should have searched ELU before posting. Sorry.